# 404 page not found in spring mvc example on clicking the link

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to Spring framework especially Spring MVC. I am writing code to display a simple message. So index.jsp is the form class in which on hitting the Click Here link the request should get forwarded to hellopage.jsp and print the message. But on clicking the link it is giving 404 error.  According to me all the names and configurations are fine but it just doesnt go and prints the message. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Folder structure in eclipse**
[image: Folder structure in eclipse]

**index.jsp**
[image: index.jsp]

**web.xml**
[image: web.xml]

**spring-servlet.xml**
[image: spring-servlet.xml]

**helloWorldController.java**
[image: helloWorldController.java]

**hellopage.jsp**
[image: hellopage.jsp]

Comment: If you want specific help, you need to write a specific problem i.e.., provide the details.

Comment: Folder structure in eclipse link points to same image as index.jsp. In index.jsp, the click here link has an href of hello.html is that intended? Based on your description it sounds like you want "/hello"

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
<a href = "hello.html">click here</a>
```

to

```
<a href = "/hello">click here</a>
```

in your **index.jsp** file
It looks like you have placed your **index.jsp** and **hellopage.jsp** files in /WEB-INF/JSP folder. Keep those files under WebContent folder and change the line

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />
```

to

```
<property name="prefix" value="/" />
```